# Deactivate cursor hover breadcrumb

Tags: html, css, hover, breadcrumbs

I'm following this [tuto](https://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/), and I got what I want it only for one thing, I want to deactivate the hand of the cursor when hovering over it.

Here's the HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h:ul class="breadcrumb">
            <div id="savedStateDiv">
                <h:a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    Drafted
                </h:a>
            </div>
            <div id="confirmedStateDiv">
                <h:a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    sent
                </h:a>
            </div>
            <div id="reopenedStateDiv">
                <h:a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    shutdown
                </h:a>
            </div>
            <div id="validatedStateDiv">
                <h:a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    Validated
                </h:a>
            </div>
            <div id="invoicedStateWithoutCRADiv">
                <h:a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    signed
                </h:a>
            </div>
            <div id="invoicedCompletedStateDiv">
                <h:a href="javascript:void(0);">
                    finished
                </h:a>
            </div>
        </h:ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already commented out :

```
.breadcrumb li a:hover { 
    background: hsla(34, 85%, 25%, 1); 
}
.breadcrumb li a:hover:after { 
    border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 25%, 1) !important; 
}
```

but still, when I hover the breadcumb, the cursor pointer is changed to a hand. thanks

Comment: Change the "cursor" attribute... It must be part of the css. Change it to cursor: default;

Comment: The pointer cursor is most likely set as default for all links in your stylesheet somewhere (or maybe even the browser stylesheet.) If you want a different cursor for these specific links - then simply _specify it_.

Comment: _“Here's the HTML :”_ - that’s not really HTML, btw. Next time, please provide the actual HTML code for example purposes.

Comment: @NikhilEshvar, your solution woked perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.breadcrumb li a:hover:after { 
  border-left-color: hsla(34, 85%, 25%, 1) !important; 
  cursor:none;
```

}

Not sure is this you are looking for ? Also refer https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/

Comment: thanks, but instead of none, I puted default and it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the cursor to keep its default `pointer` look when hovering, use `cursor: pointer;`:

```
.breadcrumb li a:hover { 
  cursor: pointer;
}
```